# Code keeps adding a space

Tags: php, mysql

I've bought a script that uses a database to for elements like the page site, meta tags etc. The problem is that when the data is added to the page a space or two is also added. The script is using

```
    <?php echo siteinfo("sitetitle");?>
```

to add the data to the page, but I also found this function:

```
    function siteinfo($att)

{

    include("linkmysql.php");
    $att=mysql_real_escape_string($att);
    $query="Select value from settings where attribute='$att'";

    if ($q=mysql_query($query,$link))

        if ($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))

        {

            $r[0]=stripslashes($r[0]);

            return $r[0];

        }

    return FALSE;

}
```

yet I can't work out how it's adding the space and how to remove it so would be grateful for any help. I've checked the database and the space isn't there so it's only being added when the code is added to the page.

Thanks

Comment: You actually bought this? Maybe space is in HTML, or in database.

Comment: There's no reason for additional spaces because of that script. But blank spaces in the source-code does not matter anyway. How does your rendered html look like?

Comment: Look at the "view" code ... if it's something like `<title>   <?php echo ... ; ?>    </title>` you're gonna have spaces there; either that or there are spaces in the database... those are the 2 most obvious cases anyway.

Comment: That code isn't adding any spaces in itself. Can you provide an example of a code block using `siteinfo()` and the output?

Comment: well my boss bought it and I'm trying to get rid of errors in it lol. I've checked the view code and the spaces aren't there at all. The siteinfo() block, such as <title><?php echo siteinfo("pagetitle");?></title> will out put <title>  Home</title>

Answer (score 3):

Replace this `return $r[0];` with this `return trim($r[0]);`.

Rewritten, couldn't look at it.

```
function siteinfo($att)
{

    require_once 'linkmysql.php';

    $att = mysql_real_escape_string($att);

    $query = "SELECT value FROM settings WHERE attribute = '$att' LIMIT 1";

    $query = mysql_query($query, $link);

    if ($query)
    {
        if ($r = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $r[0] = stripslashes($r[0]);
            return trim($r[0]);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work, it removed all the text, but kept the spaces instead lol

Comment: Haha impossibru. Post HTML, post screenshot of row in database (select it, if there are spaces you should see it).

Comment: the html is <title><?php echo siteinfo("sitetitle");?></title> I'm not sure how to post a screengrab though

Comment: It looks fine, I think stripslashes is not necessary... go to your settings table in database, find sitetitle (Home), click edit, select it with mouse, and see if there are any spaces.

Comment: I've tried that and there's no spaces there at all, that's what's really baffling me

Answer (score 0):

If this function is *really* where it happens, then you may need an additional 'trim'.

Try to replace this : `$r[0]=stripslashes($r[0]);` by `$r[0]=trim(stripslashes($r[0]));`

[**EDIT :**] Following the comments, it could be the `include("linkmysql.php");` file that contains additional space.

That would explain why you get a space character **before** the title.

Please check for any space before the `<?php` or after the `?>` in *linkmysql.php* file.

Comment: Then it is not in this function nor in the database. Please paste the HTML source in [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com/), and give us a link to see **where the spaces** are.

Comment: At the moment it's all password protected so I can't paste a link, but the html is <title><?php echo siteinfo("pagetitle");?></title> which is outputting <title>  Home Page</title>

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that **linkmysql.php contains an additional space** somewhere outside the php brackets. Please check that.

Comment: This is the code in the linkmysql.php file: `<?php

 include("../includes/config.php");

 $link = mysql_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword);

 mysql_select_db("$databasename");

?>` and the config.php is only the database details

Comment: Then drill down to config.php and check for extra spaces there also